# Jersey setup on app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey

I recently added jersey to my app engine project, everything works great on my local machine but when I try to access the page on the deployed site I get errors.  I think I might be including an unsupported class, but I don't think I'm using any.  Most of my code is an exact copy from this guide to setting up [jQuery upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Google-App-Engine-Java)

Here is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("/url")
public Response getCallbackUrl() {
  /* this is /_ah/upload and it redirects to its given path */
  String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/rest/file");
  return Response.ok(new FileUrl(url), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.thedailycaption</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
           <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

here is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.<init>(ContainerRequest.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createRequest(WebComponent.java:450)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:380)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.thedailycaption.Controller.FacebookLogin.doFilter(FacebookLogin.java:165)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

Here are the errors on startup:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-51d788e4ae40f0dc(Request.java)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:253)
at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
```

and

```
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomEntryProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomEntryProvider
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-51d788e4ae40f0dc(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:253)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
```

and

```
    com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomFeedProvider
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-51d788e4ae40f0dc(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:253)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initWriters(MessageBodyFactory.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1310)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:168)
```

and

```
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory __getComponentProvider: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomEntryProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class com.sun.jersey.atom.rome.impl.provider.entity.AtomEntryProvider
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-51d788e4ae40f0dc(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:253)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:131)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
```

and

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:282)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayProperty.<init>(ArrayProperty.java:69)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.<init>(ArrayERProperty.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:33)
```

Comment: Can you post your web.xml so we can see the jersey servlet mappings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableWADL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

to web.xml

This prevents classes that use reflection, which is not allowed on app engine.